# Deploy to Google App Engine Issue

Tags: google-app-engine, laravel, laravel-4

I am facing the following error while trying to access the site after deployed my laravel application to google apps engine.

```
" file_put_contents(/base/data/home/apps/s~s3-xxx/1.375387353027960317/
app/storage/views/d28c8e9a45dcf7bb92eeb3479241249b): 
failed to open stream: Read-only file system"
```

Any idea how to resolve this issue? Sorry but I am new to GAE. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You cannot write to the file system on App Engine. You can store a file in the Blobstore or in the Google Cloud Storage.